# Intermitant noise

Tags: gears

My merlin road bike makes an intermitant noise, like a high whirring, humming sound while I'm riding or coasting and than goes away. Sounds like its coming from the the drivetrain or geared hubs?

Comment: Sounds like tire whine to me.

Comment: Do you have mudguards/fenders? I've known these to intermittently brush against the tyre.

Comment: @sidney please add more information or the question will be closed.  Use the Edit link below your question to expand.

Comment: 3 months later, vote to close for no further info.

Answer (score 1):

So the noise persists whether you're pedalling or coasting?  Means that its something moving all the time.

Some things to check

- the tyres for lodged stones or sticky stuff
- the tyres for rubber sprues that are hitting the frame or something else hard
- the wheel bearings - pick up the bike and spin a wheel hard, and feel for play or crunchiness in bearings
- for loose things that may be buzzing or vibrating
- the frame for cracks or excessive bendiness
- cables and so on that may be buzzing against the frame at certain resonant speeds.  QR levers might do this but would have to be loose.
- all bolts and fasteners to make sure they're not loose